# Minimize imports size (js)

Tags: javascript

[image]

I've installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wix.vscode-import-cost (import cost) extension and mentioned that some imports cost really a lot. I increase my bundle size dramatically. Is there exist any approach to minimize it?

Comment: I don't know if this extension considers tree shaking. I think material-ui has tree shaking so only what you import is bundled in the final package. If the extension does consider tree shaking and those are the correct values, there's nothing much you can do if you need those exact deps.

Comment: @Phiter, let's imagine that I will import it only once on the top level and then will pass it like a property by using react context , can it be like optimization and will decrease size of my bundle , or it is bad idea ?

Comment: @AndreyRadkevich I like that idea, could you present a code sandbox for it ?